# Methods and problems with output

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I was trying to learn Java techniques.
What's the problem with this code, why can't I print anything?

```
public class CarLoan {
int carLoan = 10000;
int loanLenght = 3; //This will represent a loan length of 3 years.
int interestRate = 5; //This will represent an interest rate of 5% on the loan
int downPayment = 2000; //This will represent the down payment provided by a user for this car purchase.


 public CarLoan() {
    if (loanLenght <= 0 && interestRate <=0) {
      System.out.println("Error! You must take out a valid car loan");
    } else if (downPayment >= carLoan){
      System.out.println("The car can be paid in full");
    }else{
      int remainingBalance = carLoan - downPayment; 
      int months = loanLenght * 12;
      int monthlyBalance = remainingBalance / months; 
      System.out.println("false");
    }
 }



public static void main(String[] args) {
CarLoan masterTask = new masterTask();
System.out.println(CarLoan);
}
}
```

I tried changing the method, making it `void` and listing variables in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: *As a guess*... Neither line in the `main` method makes any sense.  You declare a variable of type `CarLoan` and try to create an object of type `masterTask` (which isn't shown here), then try to print the *class* `CarLoan`?  Did you just mean this?: `System.out.println(new CarLoan());`

Comment: You appear to be rather confused, writing stuff without a clear idea about why or how. Programming is hard and we all start somewhere, but when things aren't working and errors are pointing at the places where you've just sort of typing some stuff hoping it'll work, I suggest you try to understand it, or search for tutorials to focus on it.

Comment: It's `CarLoan masterTask = new CarLoan(); System.out.println(masterTask);`. `CarLoan masterTask;` - decree that there exists a reference (like a page in an addressbook) that can refer to CarLoan objects. We shall name it `masterTask`. `new CarLoan()` make a new CarLoan instance. `=` - write the address of this newly created instance down on the addressbook page we called `masterTask` (masterTask, the variable, refers to the new instance)`. `System.out.println(masterTask)` - call println. Make a copy of your `masterTask` reference and pass it along with the call.

Comment: "What's the problem with this code, why can't I print anything?" Hello. What makes you think that there is problem in your code? Can you explain what do you *expect* to happen vs what happens *instead*? Are you getting compilation error, runtime exception, or some other unexpected behavior? To help you ask better questions in the future please consider reading this [article about asking questions when something "doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)

Answer (score 1):

`masterTask` is a variable of type `CarLoan`. You have missused it in the statement when you tried create an instance of `CarLoan`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
CarLoan masterTask = new CarLoan();
System.out.println(masterTask);
}
```

Then you should create a method `toString()` to print the object.

---

You have also misunderstood the purpose of the constructor in Java. It is not used for doing calculations. If you want an object is doing something then you should create a method, then call this method when you created an instance of the object. Variables keep instance of the object as reference and can be used to call a method of this object.

```
public String makeCarLoan() {
  String result;
    if (loanLenght <= 0 && interestRate <=0) {
      result = "Error! You must take out a valid car loan";
    } else if (downPayment >= carLoan){
      result = "The car can be paid in full";
    }else{
      int remainingBalance = carLoan - downPayment; 
      int months = loanLenght * 12;
      int monthlyBalance = remainingBalance / months; 
      result = "false";
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Then you can rewrite previous code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
CarLoan carLoan = new CarLoan();
System.out.println(carLoan.makeCarLoan());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... What's the problem with this code, why can't I print anything? ..."*

Your *[declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)* is incorrect.

```java
CarLoan masterTask = new masterTask();
```

Create a *new* *"CarLoan"*, instead.

```java
CarLoan masterTask = new CarLoan();
```

Additionally, send *masterTask* to *println*, and not *CarLoan*.

```java
System.out.println(masterTask);
```